# IONIC Application showing no internet connection

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid, internet-connection

I have successfully installed cordova network plugin and no errors so far from the code side.

When I use `ionic serve` to get the app to run on my browser, it detects my wifi and the plugin recognizes a connection, and if i disable wifi on my computer, it again recognizes that there is no internet connection.

The problem now comes when I install the app onto an android phone after building. I even have Bluestacks on my computer but the app does not get the network from there too. Has anyone run into this problem? How did you go through it?

I do not think it is an issue with my code, so I am not posting code, unless someone will need it for clarification.

I hope someone is able to help.

Permission in androidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

config.xml do include:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved : As Permission Issue Held Due to Permission Was Listed in Dangerous Permission.

I Lowered my TargetSDKVersion